# How can I make an interface work with casting

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, casting

So, I am programming my Python Program with the MVC-Architecture, and I want everything nice and seperated from each other. I don't want the View of my GUI having to work with the Controllers instance and so on. So I made an 'IController' abstract class which is the parent of 'Controller', which has all of the functions. In 'IController' I have the functions my Model and View need to access. The Controller looks somewhat like this:

```
class IController:
     def method(self):
          pass

class Controller(IController):
     self.x = 'Hello'
     def method(self):
          print('self.x)
```

So where I previously had

```
class Frame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__ (self, controller):
            self.controller = controller
    button = tk.Button(self, command=lambda: self.controller.method()
```

I now want to turn this into

```
class Frame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__ (self, controller):
            self._controller = type(controller)
    button = tk.Button(self, command=lambda: self._controller.method()
```

The problem here is, that when I do this, I can't keep the instance of my 'Controller' Class. I need this, since the instance has values and methods I need to work with here. I also can't save the instance of 'Controlle'r in 'IController' since it is an abstract class, so I won't instance it and can't save anything in it.

I expected it to just work, but I am not sure if this is possible now. I read that casting is not possible in python, but I think there must be another way for me to fix this. When I ran it, it told me that I am lacking 'self'. I can't send the instance of the Controller with it, then it would not be capsulated. Is there a way around this?

Comment: It seems to be impossible. Your choices are 1) Have all methods of Controller to be defined as `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`. 2) have an instance `controller` instead of `type(controller)`.

Answer (score 0):

For other people who might try the same: It is not possible to do this like you would do it in C# or others. I solved it by re-writing my program in and learning C#. That and some ugly workarounds are the only possibilities.